# Creating bar plots using ggplot, running into issues with data format

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to create some bar plots of alpha diversity similar to those seen in https://besjournals.onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/full/10.1111/1365-2664.14586?campaign=wolearlyview  (Figure 2)

For context I am studying microbial diversity in different plants. I am relatively new to ggplot, usually manage to work through these things but I am stumped. I have ensured my data is really a data frame but when trying to create any plots I get the following error message:

> Error in `fortify()`: ! `data` must be a <data.frame>, or an object
> coercible by `fortify()`, not a double vector.

My dataframe is the following:

[image: data frame image, added because copying and pasting table was not clear]

I feel like the issue is probably some way the data frame is set up but I am struggling to find out how.

Thank you for any help.

First I read in my data, then created a data frame:

```r
alpha_metrics <- read.csv("Alpha_metrics.csv") 
alpha_df <- as.data.frame(alpha_metrics)
```

I have managed to get a relatively useless plot with:

```r
plot <- ggplot(data = alpha_df, aes(y=rich)) +
  geom_bar()
```

I have noticed that doing this I cannot define `x=` and `y=`, only one or the other.

Comment: It's easier to help you if you include a simple [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input and desired output that can be used to test and verify possible solutions. Please [do not post code or data in images](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/2372064)

Comment: You need geom_col, not geom_bar

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are trying to create but try adding a group to your aes e.g. ggplot aes(group=hostg) and then +facet_wrap(vars(site))

Comment: Thank you for your help, sorry for poor querstion writing, first time using stack overflow. You were right that geom_col() has been able to produce the kind of graphs I want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are probalbly looking for something like this (example from the iris data frame)

> ggplot(data = iris, aes(y=Sepal.Length, x=Species)) + geom_col()

Comment: Hi toxibilix, welcome to SO. The thing that makes SO such a valuable resource is the focus on questions that are [reproducible](https://stackoverflow.com/at/76995406/2530121) and answers that can be proven to solve the question at hand. While your answer _might_ solve this issue, there is no way to verify it as the OP did not provide enough information. Please familiarise yourself with [how to write a good answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer), especially the bit about well-asked questions. Thanks

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion though! You were right geom_col() is starting to produce the plot I want.